# forward udp multicast from eth0 to docker0

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker container running a java application which is listening for UDP multicast packets. I am not receiving the packets inside the container, however they appear on the host machine on eth0.

Is there a way for docker to automatically pick up these packets and forward them to the container?

Thanks

Comment: does privileged of cap-add=NET_ADMIN help?  https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration

Comment: @Greg Yes, I tried and nothing happens (as a matter of fact, the container is running in privileged mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of frustrating days of trying out a number of things... finally something worked:

Using Pipework (https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework), the following command worked but there is a catch -

```
pipework eth2 $(docker run -d hipache /usr/sbin/hipache) 50.19.169.157/24
```

running a docker container by only running the above command did not quite help me. I had to run `tcpdump -i eth2` **on my host** to capture packets on eth2 interface, which then started to forward the packets to the docker container.

Any idea why is worked and not just running the command??

Comment: Running tcpdump likely put the interface into promiscuous mode. Try `ip link set eth2 promisc on` instead of `tcpdump -i eth2`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try `--net host` as it seems to be the only work around for getting multicast traffic outside of the host to reach the container according to the discussions on [#3043](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3043).

Comment: thanks but actually that would not work for me. I am also doing --link to link up other container so cant use --net=host along with --link.